# Issue in deleting supersets in Matlab

Tags: matlab, subset

I have a set of data consisting of sets i want to remove super sets for which subsets are present as follows:

```
a{1} = [5]
a{2} = [4 11 14]
a{3} = [1]
a{4} = [5 16]
a{5} = [5]
a{6} = [11 16]
a{7} = [11]
a{8} = [16]
a{9} = [9 14 17]
a{10} = [14]

[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(a));
s = cellfun(@(x,y) all(ismember(x,y)), a(ii), a(jj));
s = triu(s,1); %// count each pair just once, and remove self-pairs
similarity = a(~any(s,1));
celldisp(similarity)
```

the result is as follows:

```
a{1} = [5]
a{2} = [4 11 14]
a{3} = [1]
a{4} = [11 16]
a{5} = [11]
a{6} = [16]
a{7} = [9 14 17]
a{8} = [14]
```

as the output shows there are still supersets that should be removed i.e. `a{2}` because `a{5}` contains `11` which is its subset,`a{4}` should be removed because `a{5}` contains `11` and `a{6}` contain `16` as well as `a{7}` should be deleted too because `a{8}` contains subset `14`.

expected output is

```
a{1} = [5] 
a{2} = [1]
a{3} = [11]
a{4} = [16]
a{5} = [14]
```

Can anyone help me get accurate set of results?

Comment: Could you write down the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar i've updated my question with expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the lower triangular part instead of the upper:

```
s = tril(s,-1); % instead of s = triu(s,1);
```

**Edit**

Keeping the lower triangular part only works when the supersets always occur before the subsets. Here is a general version that should always work fine.

```
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(a));
s = cellfun(@(x,y) all(ismember(x,y)), a(ii), a(jj));
% Set diagonal to zero.
s = s - diag(diag(s));
% Indicator matrix for sets that are exactly equal.
same = s & s';
% For equal sets keep only the first occurence.
keep = triu(same) | ~same.*s;
% Delete supersets.
similarity = a(~any(keep,1));
celldisp(similarity)
```

By the way, it might be easier to just run a double loop instead of the above matrix operations.

Comment: thanks for your answer it worked, can u explain in a line why upper triangular part was not giving desired results

Comment: one more question i wanted to ask you, what if instead of deleting the super sets i simply want to replace them with sub sets in above code, and we should keep the duplicates i.e `a{1}= [1 2 3]` and `a{2}= [2 3]` so the output should be  `a{1}= [2 3]` and `a{2}= [2 3]`