# How to replace supersets with their subsets in matlab?

Tags: matlab, subset

This is a follow up question to [Issue in deleting supersets in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679604/issue-in-deleting-supersets-in-matlab). in previous question I was deleting the supersets and keeping the sub sets for which I have a working answer now I want to replace the supersets with there subsets rather than deleting them for example I have a data set as follows:

```
a{1} = [5]
a{2} = [4 11 14]
a{3} = [1]
a{4} = [5 16]
a{5} = [5]
a{6} = [11 16]
a{7} = [11]
a{8} = [16]
a{9} = [9 14 17]
a{10} = [14]

[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(a));
s = cellfun(@(x,y) all(ismember(x,y)), a(ii), a(jj));
% Set diagonal to zero.
s = s - diag(diag(s));
% Indicator matrix for sets that are exactly equal.
same = s & s';
% For equal sets keep only the first occurence.
keep = triu(same) | ~same.*s;
% Delete supersets.
similarity = a(~any(keep,1));
celldisp(similarity)
```

when I run above code the output is as follows:

```
a{1} = [5] 
a{2} = [1]
a{3} = [11]
a{4} = [16]
a{5} = [14]
```

I want to do is to replace super sets with subsets rather than deleting them:

expected output should be as follows:

```
a{1} = [5]
a{2} = [11]
a{3} = [1]
a{4} = [5]
a{5} = [5]
a{6} = [11]
a{7} = [11]
a{8} = [16]
a{9} = [14]
a{10} = [14]
```

Comment: Please explain the expected output. Why is `a{4}` 5 and not 16? Does this matter or should any existing subset be picked?

Comment: because in a loop the single value `5` comes first when we go from top to down, we start with pairs and come down to single selements if there was `16` in `a{4}` than it would be `16` at location `a{4}`

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What is exactly the rule to obtain that output?

Comment: @LuisMendo the rule is simple, `if there is a super set and its subset is present replace superset with its sub set` for example `a{1}=[1 2 3]` and `a{2}= [2 3]` so replace `a{1}` with value of `a{2}`. this should be done for every `a{n}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m = arrayfun(@(i,j) all(ismember(a{i}, a{j})), ii, jj); %// subset relationship 
[valid, ind] = max(tril(m, -1)); %// consider only other sets with higher index
ind1 = find(valid); %// these will be replaced...
ind2 = ind(valid); %// ...by these ones
a(ind1) = a(ind2);
```